# Posting Link to Facebook Wall using iOS SDK

Tags: ios, facebook

I am currently facing a problem when trying to post add an action link to a Facebook wall post from inside my iOS application.

The link includes an address that requests a static google map. It looks for example like:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?&size=512x512&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:white%7Clabel:S%7C51.107402,6.722538&markers=color:red%7Clabel:D%7C51.110191,6.748481&markers=color:red%7Clabel:A%7C51.110171,6.748577&markers=color:red%7Clabel:C%7C51.106513,6.734447&markers=color:red%7Clabel:H%7C51.109167,6.739898&markers=color:white%7Clabel:E%7C51.114542,6.754146&sensor=false
```

When I click on the link on my Facebook wall it only is like:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?&size=512x512&maptype=roadmap&markers=color%3Awhite%7Clabel%3AE%7C51.114542%2C6.754146&sensor=false
```

The problem seems to be that somehow Facebook filters out all &markers except the last one. Anyone has an idea how to fix that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using 
url = (NSString*)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL, (CFStringRef) **URLHERE**, NULL, (CFStringRef) @"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]", kCFStringEncodingUTF8);